# How to get a value in an attribute to another attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" onfocus="EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus(event,this,12)" onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)" title="Select or deselect all items" class="s4-selectAllCbx">
```

Whenever I refresh the page, these attributes have been changed with "12" in both EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus and ToggleAllItems. Therefore, I would like to get "12" of the onfocus and set "12" to the onlick attribute with Javascript?

Comment: Why are you using inline event-binding?

Comment: Don't use inline event listeners !!!

Comment: **@Satpal, micnic**: Thank you for your response, but I am a biginner of Javascript. More than that, it is in SharePoint so that I won't change anything, because this is a complex javascript insides and it could be very difficult to me for changing a huge amount of the code. I would like to get that number and set to another one with Javascript. That's all I need.

Comment: what exactly you want ? i couldn't understand you

Comment: clarify, 1-what you have ? 2- what you want?, 3- whats your problem?

Comment: **@Amir Sherafatian**: Sorry for this inconvenience. 1- I got "12" in EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus, and "12" in ToggleAllItems. What I want here is that get "12" in EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus and set "12" to ToggleAllItems. Thank you very much.

Comment: You aware than in your posted code, these numbers have already same value?, right?!!! You have already 12 and want to set it to 12, hmm...

Comment: where `12` comes from ?

Comment: You could use `$.noop()` with will do nothing as anyway to get the result you are expecting, you don't need to do anything... Sorry but even following your multiples edits, your question still doesn't make any sense...

Comment: **@A. Wolff**: That's correct. I would like to get "12" and add it to another attribute. Could you please give me an example of $.noop()?

Comment: @PMay1903 I was joking, i'm afraid...

Comment: **@Amir Sherafatian**: This came from SharePoint. I cann't get exactly the number, so I would like to get this number from that code.

Comment: if `12` comes from a variable you can use this variable in both of handler, also you can access the variable from your handler, instead of passing to handler

Comment: **@Amir Sherafatian**: That is a good idea. However, I need to split the `onclick="ToggleAllItems(event,this,12)"` away and then add it back to the code. That's my issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you want to extract the number - the last param of the inline event listeners?

```js
//get the event, example EnsureSelectionHandlerOnFocus(event,this,12)
var event = document.getElementById('cbSelectAll').getAttribute('onfocus');

//extract the params, example event,this,12
var params = event.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];

//get the last param, example 12
var number = params.split(',')[2];

//outputs 12
console.log(number);
```

To set the onclick event number param :

```
var click = 'ToggleAllItems(event, this, NUMBER)';
click = click.replace('NUMBER', number);
document.getElementById('cbSelectAll').setAttribute('onclick', click);
```

---

Example alternatives to document.getElementById

```
//selecting the checkbox by its class (if the class is unique)
var element = document.querySelector('.s4-selectAllCbx');
console.log(element);

//alternatively selecting the checkbox by an attribute
var element = document.querySelector('[title="Select or deselect all items"]');
console.log(element);
```

or add an unique name to the checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox" ...>
```

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[name="myCheckBox"]');
console.log(element);
```

both will return the checkbox. If multiple elements has the same class or the same attribute, the first occurrence in the document will be returned. Giving the checkbox an unique class is prefered, imho, since you will have to update your code each time you change the attribute of the `title`.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the code doesn't have any "id" attribute.

Comment: OK, in your first version of the question there certainly was an id - `id="cbSelectAll"` :) Anyway, if the class is unique, `s4-selectAllCbx` seems rather specialized, use `document.querySelector('.s4-selectAllCbx');`

Comment: Thank you again but if I set an attribute as "id" for that checkbox. This would get me into problem with another function. Is there any way to apply your code without adding an "id" attribute?

Comment: Yes, use `querySelector` - have added some examples to do that. Now when it is an input element, it would be obvious to give the checkbox a `name`, like `name="myCheckBox"` and then `document.querySelector('[name="myCheckBox"]')`

Comment: That's fabulous. Thanks for your additional code and thank you very much.

Comment: **@davidkonrad**: That works very well. I can get the number of the onfocus attribute. Please help me to add that number to the onclick attribute.